# Well-defineness of Chern roots?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\mathcal{E} \to X$ be a rank $n$ (complex) vector bundle on a space $X$ (possibly with some other mild conditions to make the splitting principle holds). According to the splitting principle, there is a space $X'$ and a continuous function $f: X' \to X$ inducing an injection on the cohomology groups $H^k(X;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^k(X';\mathbb{Z})$ and such that the pullback bundle $f^*\mathcal{E} \to X'$ is a direct sum of line bundles. In that case, the total Chern class $c_\bullet(f^*\mathcal{E})$ can be written as
$$(1+x_1) \cdots (1+x_n) \in H^\bullet(X';\mathbb{Z})$$
for some $x_i \in H^2(X';\mathbb{Z})$ (and the product is the cup product). Then we call $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ the **Chern roots** of $\mathcal{E}$. Here is the question I can't understand: aren't Chern roots, by their definition, dependent on the space $X'$ that is chosen in the splitting principle? If that's the case, then why do people only talk about "*the* Chern roots" of $\mathcal{E}$? Are Chern roots unique in some sense?

Comment: You're right that $x_i$ is dependent on $X'$. (I'm not sure if there is a "minimal" $X'$ to make the roots $x_i$ canonical/universal.) However, the point is that the symmetric functions on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are always well-defined cohomology classes on $X$. One can always _pretend_ $\mathcal{E}$ splits into direct sum of line bundles and $x_i\in H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ and do whatever operations on them. At the end of the day, the operations on their symmetric functions are what we care about. So it doesn't really matter which $X'$ the roots belong to.